# find array in document and filter by years and month

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I working with nodejs and mongoose. I have a schema like this :

```
var comptesSchema = new Schema ({
name: String,
solde: Number,
user_id: Number,
operations: [{
    name: String,
    amount: Number,
    debit: Boolean,
    mensuel: Boolean,
    date: Date,
    category: String
}]
```

});

and my datas :

```
[{
"_id": "5826d10b829c732cacd92f6f",
"name": "compte courant",
"__v": 0,
"solde": -40,
"operations": [
  {
    "date": "2016-11-12T23:00:00.000Z",
    "debit": false,
    "amount": 10,
    "name": "tivoli",
    "_id": "5828b1bf42ae876e287525dc"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-11-12T23:00:00.000Z",
    "debit": false,
    "amount": 20,
    "name": "st georges",
    "_id": "5828d1e1c951b07888e79c61"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-11-11T23:00:00.000Z",
    "debit": false,
    "amount": 10,
    "name": "oiufdsouifd",
    "_id": "5828d51e679a4a7718a55b48"
  }
]}]
```

I would like find the elements in the operation array, and filter by year and month.

Do you have any idea ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume, you set your filter options for `month` and `year` as follow:

```
var month = 11;
var year = 2016;
```

Try this:

```
comptesSchema.find({'operations.date': {
    "$gte": new Date(year, month, 1),
    "$lt": new Date(year, month, 0)
  }, function (err, comptes) {
    // Get you filtered comptes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i have 2 operation : one in november and one in december.

I try this :

```
    .get('/compte/:compteId/operation/date', function(req, res) {
    var compteId = req.params.compteId;
    var month = 11;
    var year = 2016;
    Comptes.find({
        'operations.date': {
            "$gte": new Date(year, month, 1),
            "$lt": new Date(year, month, 0)
        }
    }, function(err, compte) {
        res.json(compte);
    });
})
```

But its doesn't work, i have this :

```
[{
"_id": "5826d10b829c732cacd92f6f",
"name": "compte courant",
"__v": 0,
"solde": -70,
"operations": [
  {
    "date": "2016-11-13T23:00:00.000Z",
    "debit": false,
    "amount": 10,
    "name": "test",
    "_id": "58297e475c208d081c810aec"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-12-13T23:00:00.000Z",
    "debit": false,
    "amount": 20,
    "name": "fsdf",
    "_id": "58297e655c208d081c810aed"
  }
]}]
```

it's return the date in november and december.. i don't understand :(